# How to work with HTML 5 input type range?

Tags: javascript, html

How to change the size of a font using the range input type in html?

```
<input type="range" name="points" min="1" max="10">
```

I want it this way, when I drag the slider, the font size should change according to the value of the slider range.

Comment: Show us our code if you want us to fix it. Or ask a more precise question.

Answer (score 1):

This one is quite very easy. You can use `oninput="myFunction()"` attribute on the input. or put a `addEventListener("input",myFunction)` in your javascript. This should make it so that it does it live.

If this isn't what you are looking for than you can use a for loop on it and using the `getElementsByTagName("*")`

Here is another example, you can also use onchange as well but I chose to use oninput.

```js
function myFunction(){
 var para = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
    var input = document.getElementById("ranger");
    for (var i = 0; i < para.length; i++){
     para[i].style.fontSize = input.value + "px";
    }
}
```

```css
p {
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div>You can also use the onchange attribute to set it when it just changes. Using oninput executes when user gives input</div>
<input type="range" id="ranger" value="50" oninput="myFunction()">
<p>First Paragraph</p>
<p>Second Paragraph</p>
<p>Third Paragraph</p>
```

Here is a fiddle that shows an example using the onchange attribute
**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rtv5wsjm/)**

Answer (score 0):

On change event of the slider, change the size accordingly by value:

```
<input type="range" name="points" min="1" max="10" id="MySlider">

$("#MySlider").change(function() {
    $("#MyText").css("font-size", $("#MySlider").value); 
  });
```